# How to fix "Permission Denied" in pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I'm making a simple program that displays a single image on the screen, but while it tries to look for the file, it gives me an error saying that permission is denied to that directory.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()

filePath = r"C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\MyGame\assets\images"
image = pyglet.image.load(filePath)

@window.event
def onDraw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0, 0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Users\\Amine\\Desktop\\MyGame\\assets\\images'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a folder instead of an image.
This is the correct way of loading an image in pyglet.

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()

filePath = r"C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\MyGame\assets\images\image_name.png"
image = pyglet.image.load(filePath)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0, 0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

You need to give it an actual image. It could be a png or jpg file.
And the draw function should have this name: on_draw() not onDraw()